# Remove the WebKitFormBoundary in C#

Tags: stream, png, multipart, system.io.file

I am working on the server that receives a file stream uploaded by multipart uploader.

But I got an additional WebKitFormBoundary.

If I remove it manually, it will work. So I tried the following code:

```
var fileStream = File.Create(@"C:\Users\myname\Desktop\myimage.png");
stream sr = new streamReader(myStream);
string myText = sr.ReadToEnd();
string newText = myText.Substring(myText.IndexOf("‰")); // remove header
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(newText);
MemoryStream data = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
data.CopyTo(filestream);
```

If I use the above way to convert it to string, remove boundary and convert back to stream
the first character "‰" will become "?"
(ie. So ‰PNG will become ?PNG and the file becomes not readable.)

Any suggestions?
Where could I possible got wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This drove me nuts.  Finally understood that if you have access to the request, you can access just the contents (with no header) like this:

```
var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
var file = await provider.Contents[0].ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

Hope this helps you, or someone with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue but after investigating several blogs with applied several solutions, I got final working one. Please follow below code approach to fix it.

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream, Encoding.Default, true);
memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

string fileString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
string fileData = fileString.Substring(0, fileString.IndexOf("\r\n\r\n") + 4);
string finalData = Regex.Replace(fileString, fileData, "");

var fileDataArr = Regex.Split(fileData, "\r\n|\r|\n").ToList();
var resultData = Regex.Replace(finalData, fileDataArr[0] + "--", "");

byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(resultData);
```

Steps:

1. Convert your filedata into memory stream which can be used to read file content.
2. Use StreamReader to read file content and remove webkitformBoundary Header with default Encoding format.
3. Code To remove first 4 lines including webkitformBoundary from Top.
4. Code to remove webkitformBoundary from Footer.
5. Convert the string into Byte Array with default encoding format to maintain the file Encoding format.

Example:

```
WebKitFormBoundary Header

------WebKitFormBoundaryL1NUALe5NDrNt9S0 <br/>
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userfile"; filename="BRtestfile1.pdf" <br/>
Content-Type: application/pdf <br/>


WebKitFormBoundary Footer

------WebKitFormBoundaryL1NUALe5NDrNt9S0-- <br/>
```