# Upload Excel to Web API .net 6, Prefixes and Suffixes WebKitFormBoundary

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-core-webapi

How to remove the Prefix and Suffix received in the Request Body stream.
Since the Stream has the below shown Prefix and Suffix, the Excel file is considered as corrupt.

Prefix:

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryHPmAnEEfrdAJAffE Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="filename.xlsx" Content-Type:
> application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet*

Suffix:

> ------WebKitFormBoundarySIEFl8xpvJoj5fIi--

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me

```
[HttpPost, Route("UploadExcel")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadExcel()
    {
        var request = HttpContext.Request;

        if (!request.HasFormContentType ||
          !MediaTypeHeaderValue.TryParse(request.ContentType, out var mediaTypeHeader) ||
          string.IsNullOrEmpty(mediaTypeHeader.Boundary.Value))
        {
            return new UnsupportedMediaTypeResult();
        }

        var reader = new MultipartReader(mediaTypeHeader.Boundary.Value, request.Body);
        var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();

        while (section != null)
        {
            var hasContentDispositionHeader = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse(section.ContentDisposition,
                out var contentDisposition);

            if (hasContentDispositionHeader && contentDisposition.DispositionType.Equals("form-data") &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentDisposition.FileName.Value))
            {
                var fileuploadPath = "D:\\test\\test.xlsx";

                using (var targetStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileuploadPath))
                {
                    await section.Body.CopyToAsync(targetStream);
                }

                return Ok();
            }

            section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

Taken from this Microsoft Documentation:
[Upload files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Convert your filedata into memory stream which can be used to read file content.
2. Use StreamReader to read file content and remove webkitformBoundary Header with default Encoding format.
3. Code To remove first 4 lines including webkitformBoundary from Top.
4. Code to remove webkitformBoundary from Footer.
5. Convert the string into Byte Array with default encoding format to maintain the file Encoding format.

For details, please refer to "[Remove the WebKitFormBoundary in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61264628/remove-the-webkitformboundary-in-c-sharp)" and "[How do I remove the header info from the file uploaded](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2761dc76-0cd7-4bf9-94dc-bf6faf1c722d/how-do-i-remove-the-header-info-from-the-file-uploaded?forum=aspwcfasmx)".

Hope this can help you.

Comment: This was my initial try, but I couldn't come up with the correct code to trim the stream.